# Assembly: ecx not decreasing

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention, masm32, stdcall

I am using MASM and currently implementing a loop displaying Capital alphabets, small alphabets and ASCII in between

```
.386

.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include c:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include c:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include c:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 

.data
    _ret sdword 13
    _car sdword 10
    _num sdword 0


.code
main:
    mov edx, 'A'
    mov ecx, 58
    jmp _end

_loop:  
    push edx
    invoke StdOut, esp
    invoke StdOut, addr _ret
    invoke StdOut, addr _car
    pop edx

    inc edx
    dec ecx

_end:
    cmp ecx, 0
    jne _loop

_exit:    
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end main
```

The problem here I am facing is that ECX is not decreasing during the body of the loop and the loop continue forever even after A-Z %somehere% a-z

Comment: With stdcall calling convention the registers  EAX, ECX, and EDX are volatile (they can be changed by functions you call). I suspect `StdOut` clobbered your loop counter. Easiest solution is to use  a register other than EAX, ECX and EDX for the loop.

Comment: So, I should swap with a global variable?

EDIT: thanks, It now works

Comment: (a) attach debugger, look at ECX value before and after the invokes. (b) use loop instruction

Comment: In this case you even don't need a separate loop counter; use `cmp edx, 'A'+58`.  You're already saving/restoring it across the function calls that could clobber it.  You could be using `ebx` and `inc ebx` / `mov [esp], ebx` (with space on the stack for that to not overwrite anything), so you wouldn't need to pop it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is one of calling convention. You've set the default convention to `.model flat, stdcall` which is not an issue. This means that unless otherwise specified [stdcall calling convention](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/High-Level_Languages#STDCALL) will be used by the `invoke` directive. The stdcall calling convention includes these rules:

> 9. The volatile registers are: EAX, **ECX**, EDX, and ST0 - ST7
> 10. The non-volatile registers are: EBX, EBP, ESP, EDI, ESI, CS, DS, ES, FS and GS

This means that you can't assume that the values in *EAX*, *ECX*, and *EDX* will remain the same after a `call`/`invoke`. Your loop variable is *ECX* so it is likely the calls to `StdOut` clobbered *ECX* each time they were called leading to the infinite loop.

The best choice is to use one of the non-volatile registers  *EBX*, *EDI*, *ESI* (you cause other issues if you use *EBP* and *ESP*). If you run out of registers you can:

- Save and restore the value of *ECX* before and after the calls to `StdOut` the same way that *EDX* was preserved in your code using *PUSH/POP*.
- Store them in a global or stack based memory location and restore them after.
- Write the code to avoid using an extra register for the loop.

Comment: Even better option: use `cmp edx, 'A'+58` / `jne` as the loop bound; no separate counter required.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Unlike you I won't muddy the waters with something specific like that since it really pollutes the answer. Should point out _EDX_ is a bad choice to begin with since you have to save and restore. So I wouldn't actually use your solution as I wouldn't even use _EDX_ in this code. But this isn't an optimization related question so I see no sense in making a response unreadable for the average reader. If you wish to put up what you think is a better answer, be my guest.

Comment: The OP is pushing, and then passing `esp` as the pointer to the character.  Yes, it would be slightly more efficient to use `ebx` or something and just store to `[esp]` instead of reading the old value back.

Comment: Anyway, I get your point, but it seems to be a common mistake to waste a 2nd register instead of using another loop variable as the exit condition.  I don't think it needs a separate answer, I just wanted to add a footnote to yours.  I can make it a comment on the question and we can delete this clutter of comments.